# Number Triangle using user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, pascals-triangle

Trying to create a number triangle using user input for each individual part of the triangle. I figured out how to put each row into a list and get user input for each individual number but I need help doing it without having each row in a list.

```
rows = int(dataLines) # --> convert user input to an integer
def triangle(rows):
    PrintingList = list()
    for rownum in range (1, rows + 1): # use colon after control structure to denote the beginning of block of code
        PrintingList.append([]) # append a row
        for iteration in range (rownum):
            newValue = input("Please enter the next number:")
            PrintingList[rownum - 1].append(int(newValue))
            print()

    for item in PrintingList:
      print (item)
triangle(rows)
```

This only got me lists for each row.
Desired output would be something like

1

2  5

5  7  8

9  15  2  3

using user input for each individual number

Comment: And what about a nested loop then? Doesn't that solve the problem?

Comment: how would it solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change This In Your Code:-**

```
for item in PrintingList:
  print (*item)
```

Here we unpacked each element of the list using an List Unpacking Operator `*`. This got us rid of those brackets, in the beginning and end of each row.

This Gives us Output:-

```
1

2 5

5 7 8

9 15 2 3
```